# Symfony2 twig translate string containing colon

Tags: symfony, twig, translation

How can I translate string containing colon in symfony2 using twig? Here's what I have:

Inside twig template:

```
{% trans with {'%order_no%': order_no} %}Loading offer: %order_no%...{% endtrans %}
```

Inside translation file:

```
Loading offer: %order_no%...: Įkeliamas užsakymas %order_no%...
```

As expected this doesn't work. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use quotes around the text as such:

```
'Loading offer: %order_no%...': Įkeliamas užsakymas %order_no%...
```

edited to show the correct example.

Comment: Thanks! though the end result was 'Loading offer: %order_no%...': Įkeliamas užsakymas %order_no%... surrounding key to translation with quotes, but still, very helpful!

Comment: Sorry, at first glance I thought the 'Loading offer' was the key to be translated.